# Solving for a matrix which appears in the middle of a summation

Tags: matrices

I am trying to solve for a matrix $B$ from the following equation:
$$
D = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left(A_n B C_{n}\right)
$$
All other matrices except $B$ are known. $D\in\mathbb{R}^{64\times32},\:A_n\in\mathbb{R}^{64\times64},\:B\in\mathbb{R}^{64\times32}$ and $C_n\in\mathbb{R}^{32\times32}$. $A_n$ and $C_n$ are not invertible. Please help me on this. I could not do enough googling since I don't know how to search for these type of problems.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you may solve the equivalent equation $\operatorname{vec}(D)=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}C_n^\top \otimes A_n\right)\operatorname{vec}(B)$. See Wikipedia for the definitions of [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) "$\otimes$" and [vectorisation of matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) "$\operatorname{vec}(\cdot)$".

Comment: ^Thanks a lot. I have studied about the Kronecker products and Sylvester's equation. I could see some computationally efficient algorithms for solving Sylvester's equations $AX+XB=C$ and $AXB=C$ (Solve for $X$). But I could not find such an algorithm for a more generalized case as mentioned above. i.e, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}XB_{i}=C$. Does anyone know about such an efficient algorithm ?

Comment: @SandeepDevasrii I don't know. Even if $A_n$ and $C_n$ are sparse, $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}C_n^\top \otimes A_n$ can be a dense matrix. So, unless the *families* of $A_n$ and $C_n$ have some unspecified special properties, I think one can only solve the system as a usual, big system of linear equations.

Comment: Ok..I understand. Unfortunately $A_i$ and $C_i$ does not possess any other structure than symmetry. But I was just anticipating that there would be some feasible algorithms because it was available for the other similar problems. I will do another rigorous Google search :). Also, I have posted it as new question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568405/efficient-algorithm-for-generalized-sylvesters-equation) Once again thanks for your  suggestions.