# How can I solve this equation for $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

$$
\lambda XX^{T} = \lambda  TXX^{T} + \mu T + \frac{1}{n-1} CTX(I-(BA)^{-1/2}B)X^{T}.
$$

Is there any way I can solve for $T$ here when everything else besides scalars $\lambda$ and $\mu$ is a matrix? If not, are there methods to approximate the solution $T$?

Comment: Yes, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are scalars, sorry. This came from my current research.

Comment: It's an equation of the form $AXB + XC=D$ (the unknown is $X$). Assuming $B$ is regular, you can rewrite this as $AX+XB=C$ (not the same $A,B,C$). It's called [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), and there are methods to solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by regular? Do you mean invertible?

Comment: Yes. You may also have a look at [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-981-10-3677-4%2F1.pdf), which gives references on the generalized Sylvester equation, of which your is a special case. And also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568405/efficient-algorithm-for-generalized-sylvesters-equation